# I installed nginx into the wrong directory (using passenger-install-nginx-module)! How do I move it?

Tags: nginx, passenger

When I was prompted by passenger where to install nginx, I entered `~/nginx` because I expected that `~/` would be replaced with my home dir. But interestingly, nginx was installed in `/home/me/~/nginx`!

This is very annoying. So how can I remove the unwanted `~` folder from nginx's path? Should I simply uninstall nginx and reinstall it with an absolute path? How do I make sure that there are no unwanted files left from the first install?

I installed it using `gem install passenger` and `passenger-install-nginx-module`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should uninstall it and reinstall it. That is the only thing you have to do.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Uninstalling and reinstalling it?

Comment: Please reformulate your answer, then I can check it as answer. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you. Have you some references for this?

Comment: I am one of the Phusion Passenger authors.

Comment: Can you prove this? ;) Haha, joke, that's enough for me.